# How to check button click history using if-else statements ? C#

Tags: c#, forms, button, visual-studio-2015

I have a total of 4 forms(Form1,form2,form3,form4).
3 buttons(Form 1 has 2(Button1,Button2),form 2 has 1(Button3))

My situation is as follows:

Both buttons in `Form1` lead to `form2` but with different label inputs.
What I want to do is when my button 3 is clicked, and if else loop would determine what form the button leads to(form3,form4). If button1 was clicked, button 3 would lead to form3 else button3 would lead to form4.

im not sure where and what part of my code I should include while asking this question so I assume I should just put the button codes.

This is button1 code:

```
public void DIModuleButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //  MessageBox.Show("TEST");
    alloDI();
    FormSerial frm = new FormSerial();
    frm.MyProperty = ALL;
    frm.Show();
}

public void alloDI()
{
    ALL = "DI";
}
```

this is button2 code:

```
public void DOModuleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    alloDO();
    FormSerial frm = new FormSerial();
    frm.MyProperty = ALL;
    frm.Show();
}

public void alloDO()
{
    ALL = "DO";
}
```

Comment: you know that you can rename your buttons? in designer select a control, in properties change its name to something meaningful. it doesn't have to be button with numbers

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary they all have their own names, i stated them as button1 and button2 in the questions for ease of understanding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could be to use a Boolean flag ,since you have only to distinguish between 2 buttons.

Put a new `bool` property into your second form like you did already with `MyProperty`.

in Form2:

```
public bool Button1_pressed { get; set; }
```

In the Button click event you would set it accordingly:

```
public void DIModuleButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //  MessageBox.Show("TEST");
    alloDI();
    FormSerial frm = new FormSerial();
    frm.MyProperty = ALL;
    frm.Button1_pressed = true;
    frm.Show();
}
```

in the second you would set it to false

and when your third button is pressen you can check this variable.

If you have more then 2 buttons, I would suggest to use an `enum` and a switch case to check the different cases:

The property would look like this:

```
public ButtonSource MyButton_Clicked { get; set; }

// here your enum
public enum ButtonSource
{
    button1,
    button2,
    button3,
    button4
}
```

and the switch case:

```
switch (MyButton_Clicked)
{
    case ButtonSource.button1:
        break;
    case ButtonSource.button2:
        break;
    case ButtonSource.button3:
        break;
    case ButtonSource.button4:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: would this still work if i needed to distinguish between 3 buttons instead of 2? button 1 would lead to form 3, button 2 would lead to form 4 and another additional button"*button3*"(which is in form 1) , lead to an aditional form5.

Comment: @MuhammedNizamBinKamarudeen unfortunately not, since `bool` can only be `true` of `false`, for more buttons I have written a different suggestion. Check my edit

Comment: ill try this out and get back to you! Thanks alot!

Comment: Hi there, im encountering some problems with the case, currently even tho i stated my cases, any button that i pressed form 1 would lead to case 1 only and not case 2 or 3. how do i pm you with my code?

Comment: @MuhammedNizamBinKamarudeen You could ask a new question and post your code, and we take a new look onto it. Did you choose the solution with the `ENUM` ? You could also share your code online and post the link in a comment.